# How to replace multiple characters with corresponding multiple characters in php?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I want to replace multiple characters in a string with other characters i.e. say `<` to `a`, `>` to `b`, `!` to `c`, `$` to `d`, etc. I want to achieve this goal by using `preg_replace` in PHP. Can I do this in just one line of code or should I go for breaking the string , making an array and then replace it?

Comment: What? I didnt get what you actually want.

Comment: Why don't you use str_replace : http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 13):

why want you to use a regex to achieve this? just use str_replace, which is a lot faster.

```
$replace = str_replace(array('<', '>', '!'), array('a', 'b', 'c'), $text);
```

Answer (score 8):

You may use simple replace, in your case regex will be an overkill. For example:

```
$result = strtr($data, [
  '<' => 'a',
  '>' => 'b',
  '!' => 'c',
  //e t.c.
]);
```

Alternative would be [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace), but I think associative array looks more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), which is designed for this kind of character translation:

```
<?php
$string = '<<!!';
echo strtr($string, '<>!$', 'abcd');
// Output: aacc
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I'd do.

```
$string = '<>!$';

$string = str_replace('<', 'a', $string);
$string = str_replace('>', 'b', $string);
$string = str_replace('!', 'c', $string);
$string = str_replace('$', 'd', $string);

echo $string; // abcd
```

Comment: @Philipp has an answer that is way better :)

Comment: Sorry Everyone. Seems that I didn't explained the exact scenario. I'm recieving a string from $_POST which I want to tweak at some places i.e. '<' to 'ab' ,'>' to 'cd', '!' to 'ef',':' to 'gh' ,etc. My colleague told me to do this by using arrays in preg_replace. Did anyone tried this before?

Comment: @Dranzer It doesn't matter how you receive the string.  Using preg replace is wasteful as it takes longer. Unless this is like an "assignment" in which you need to use regex, using one of the above solutions will be much more appropriate for your need.  Try it!